# How to disable all visitors cookies in Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to disable all visitor cookies for my Joomla website.

I found some tutorials, but they are for Joomla version:1.x

Any suggestions?

Comment: I faced the same issue. My current workaround is to remove `Set-Cookie` http headers using apache mod_headers. In addition I followed [this](http://elmasrydev.blogspot.hu/2014/03/how-to-disable-sessions-in-joomla-3x.html) which doesn't solve the problem by itself, but could help a bit to reduce database load. I'm not too happy with this but better than nothing.

Comment: The main issue is that joomla devs feel that [it would be too complicated](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/8772#issuecomment-168973989) to implement such functionality, so there won't a be a clean solution anytime soon, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is very similar to solution to remove cookies in Joomla version 1.x and 2.x. So we will use the same condition and principle.

If you change this two files then maybe something other will not work. Change this only if you know what are you doing and if you know that will everyting else work. Because you can break the whole website!

You must edit two files /libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php and libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php

In **libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php** change code around line 166 and add if condition for whole code in method if (substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] , 0 , 14) == "/administrator"){

```
public function checkSession()
    {
      if (substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] , 0 , 14) == "/administrator"){ // added condition
        $db = \JFactory::getDbo();
        $session = \JFactory::getSession();
        $user = \JFactory::getUser();

            // ... rest of code
      }
}
```

In **libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php** change code around line 229 add if condition for whole code in method like in previous file

```
private function doSessionStart()
    {
      if (substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] , 0 , 14) == "/administrator"){ // added condition
        // Register our function as shutdown method, so we can manipulate it
        register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'save'));

        // ... rest of code
      }
 }
```

This works in Joomla 3.8.2

Note: after every Joomla update you must edit this two files again and test if this solution still works.

Comment: `checkSession()` is now different in 3.8.8

Comment: Works in 3.9.20 too

Comment: Any update for 5.x please? First file looks different, and second file no longer exists. And the function `doSessionStart()` does not exist anymore anywhere in the libraries folder.

Answer (score 1):

Set the cookie-path "/administrator" in the Admin Joomla Settings (System => Configuration).
Then the session cookies are created only for the admin area.

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and see if you can help us to resolve some questions.

Comment: Does not work with (at least) 5.x.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid all cookies for normal visitors, you need to follow the below steps.

```
First of all: Deactivate site statistics! Global configuration -> Statistics -> Statistics: No. This will stop the "mosvisitor" cookie.

Don't use the Template Chooser module, because it uses a cookie named "jos_user_template".

Be careful with components: Some might start their own PHP session. 

Now to the main point: comment out line 697 of /includes/joomla.php like this:



// setcookie( $sessionCookieName, '-', false, '/' );
```

Additional: Comment out line 25 in /offline.php:

```
// session_start();
```

This seams to be an artifact of old versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kaif, but this tutorial refers to Joomla 1.x.

In version Joomla 3.x Global Configuration > Statics - doesn't exist.
Also in folder /includes/ there is no such file as joomla.php